# Install gcloud to microsoft/dotnet:sdk container using bitbucket-pipelines.yml to automate deployments

Tags: .net-core, google-compute-engine, bitbucket-pipelines

I would like to use "gcloud" command to publish changes from bitbucket pipeline. How should I extend below definition to install gcloud reasonably fast and use it for deployment?

```
image: microsoft/dotnet:sdk

pipelines:
  branches:
    dev:
    - step:
        name: Build and test
        caches:
          - dotnetcore
        script:
          - export PROJECT_NAME=app.sln
          - export TEST_NAME=app.Tests
          - dotnet restore
          - dotnet build $PROJECT_NAME
          - dotnet test $TEST_NAME
          - dotnet publish
```